# check if object is null

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

suppose I have a class called Customer (Auto-generated by Entity Framework)

```
CustomerID // Primary Key & Auto-increment
Name
Gender
City
```

Now In my ViewModel:

```
public Class myViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Customer CurrentCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return MainViewModel.cCustomer;
        }
        set
        {
            myViewModel.cCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCustomer");
        }
    }

    ....
    ....
    ....

}
```

Here is my MainViewModel

```
public Class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
       cCustomer = new Customer();
    }

    public static Customer cCustomer { get; set; }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        //Here I want to check if all the fields of cCustomer are empty
        //And depending on that I want to save the cCustomer.
    }

    ....
    ....
    ....

}
```

I have tried to check all the fields of cCustomer by comparing them to null but there I get an error stating that object reference not set to an instance of the object.

In short I want to check if cCustomer is null or not at the time of saving the customer.

Comment: `if (cCustomer != null)` doesn't work?

Comment: Attach the debugger and see what is null?

Comment: Is cCustomer ever instantiated or initialized?

Comment: @Tim (!(cCustomer == null))  too cumbersome to read. Maybe you want (cCustomer != null)

Comment: If `cCustomer` is null, you won't be able to check the fields, so you need to see if the containing object (`cCustomer` in this case) is null first.  If it's not, then you can check the individual properties.

Comment: do you initialise the ViewModel? and how? check if it is initialised from the view.

Comment: @Tim that does not work because I initialize the cCustomer in the constructor of my mainviewmodel.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis - Yes, you're correct.  Sorry - still waking up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainViewModel` class declares the `cCustomer` property as static, but you're setting that property in the class constructor:

```
public Class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
       cCustomer = new Customer();
    }

    public static Customer cCustomer { get; set; }
```

Because of this, when you try to access the `cCustomer` property statically in these lines, it may not be populated:

```
get
{
    // Unless you've created an instance of a MainViewModel already,
    // this property will be null
    return MainViewModel.cCustomer;
}
set
{
    myViewModel.cCustomer = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCustomer");
}
```

Do you really want the `cCustomer` property to be static?  Additionally, setting a static property on a class within an instance constructor is probably a bad practice, and should be avoided.

Comment: I have made that member static because I want to access the current instance of my `Mainviewmodel` in `myViewModel`. If there is any way of accessing the current instance of mainViewModel then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your `cCustomer` is `null` (there's no validation on the property set) - easy enough to check though:

```
if (cCustomer == null)
{
    // No Customer record, so don't even think about checking properties on it.
    // feel free to throw an exception if it's not valid to save without one...
}
```

Comment: Its not that easy. I invoke `cCustomer = new Customer()` in MainViewModel's constructor as I mentioned in my question. So, cCustomer will never be null.

Comment: It can be null though, e.g: `var model = new MainViewModel(); model.cCustomer = null;`. Of course, your debugger is an awesome tool for checking what is null, and setting breakpoints for when it becomes such.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that there... that should be part of your data model. If your requirement is that there should be no `null` values, then do that at the class property level:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return text; }
    set { if (value != null) { text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Text"); } }
}
```

Comment: My requirement is not that there should be no null values. I want to explain you my problem in deep. I have 15 pages in my project. On mainwindow I have a frame and a menu, so user can navigate from one page to another and they might fill values in some pages and they might not even open some pages. When user is done he/she  will have to click on save button which is the only way to save changes and that button is located on my main window.